# Is there an easy way to make a .exe file from C source files on a Mac?

Tags: c, windows, macos, exe

I wrote a chess engine on my mac and I am trying to run it on my more powerful windows machine. I need to run it with WinBoard, so that involves running things from CMD and hooking up the engine file, which should be a .exe, to the engine. The problem I am having is that it doesn't appear that my Windows machine has a command line c compiler and it is incredible troublesome to work with IDE's (I never do) because they require you to go through a wizard to create each of the 25 or so source files and then they make .o files, not .exe's. My question is, what would be the easiest way to get my .c source files on my mac to run with WinBoard on my pc? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (GCC port for Windows) and you'll get a command-line C compiler. Be advised that you will most likely need to tweak your code, because Windows is poorly POSIX compatible.

Answer (score 1):

[equation.com](http://equation.com/) has a nicely packaged gcc compiler and MinGW tools.

Or you can also try [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/).

Also, I think the Microsoft compiler can be used from the command line without a project file.

Answer (score 0):

The native C (and C++) compiler for Windows is of course the Microsoft compiler. You can get the free Express Edition here:

[Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)

Even though is contains a "troublesome IDE", you can just create an empty project and add all your existing source files too it. The wizard only has to run once...